# Laravel 5 Can't send data from url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

Hi Im currently trying to make a basic crud for my questions resource on laravel 5

so far so good, but now Im having troubles displaying the edit view, because the url is not being created correctly when I try to send the resource id in the url

here's the anchor Im using

```
<a href="{{route('admin/questions/update',$question->id)}}"><button class="submit-form button button btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0 1em;" type="submit">Editar</button></a>
```

here's the route in my routes file

```
Route::get('admin/preguntas/editar/{id}','QuestionsController@edit')->name('admin/questions/update');
```

the method in the controller works just fine, when I manually type this url

/admin/preguntas/editar/4

It shows the view without problems, but when I go from the anchor the url it goes is this one

/admin/preguntas/editar?4

of course the 4 is the id from my resource, but why is not typing the correct url?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have an a tag around a button?

Comment: im kinda new on this....can I use the href property directly on the button tag without the anchor?

Comment: Button is used to submit a form, a is used for a hyperlink.  You don't use a hyperlink to submit a form. Without more context, I don't know what you're trying to do here, but I'd recommend you read up on HTML a little more before diving into PHP web apps.

Comment: because the `type="submit"` is submitting it. And guess those invalid html markup is wrapped by a form?

Comment: @AnibalCardozo share your other routes. From the looks if it, you might be using the route name `admin/questions/update` for your update `POST` route. So the link is getting generated for the update route instead. Try to rename the route to `admin/questions/edit` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap a hyperlink around a button so my assumption is your problem is related to the form action (since button type is submit), not the `a href`.

Since it appears you're using bootstrap, there is no need to use a button to get the styling of a button.

`<a class="btn btn-primary">` will work just fine.

Comment: his issue is with link generation using laravel's route helper method

Comment: @Sandeesh you can't know that for sure since a hyperlink around a form button won't work as proven here: https://jsfiddle.net/a2Lceaty/1/

Answer (score 0):

And your "QuestionsController@edit" accepts "id" argument?
like

```
function edit($id){}
```

And I think, your are using wrong route link helper

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: yeah, as I said, when I type the url manually it works just fine I recognize and use the $id without problems.

Comment: I'm update my comment I think u need use this way to display your link

route('profile', ['id' => 1]);

Comment: No, you don't need to do that.  route() accepts an array or scalar and it does not require the key, it will assign parameters in order.

Answer (score 0):

First write proper link button as [Devon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147537/7155723) said:

```
<a href="{{route('admin.questions.update', ['id' => $question->id])}}" class="submit-form button button btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0 1em;">Editar</a>
```

Second you must write proper route name format:

```
Route::get('admin/preguntas/editar/{id}','QuestionsController@edit')->name('admin.questions.update');
```

Hope it will help you to solve the problem :)